# pyspark: reading orc data and writing to drop duplicates increases total disk size?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is this somehow related to?

- [Why are Spark Parquet files for an aggregate larger than the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153935/why-are-spark-parquet-files-for-an-aggregate-larger-than-the-original)
- [Why does the repartition() method increase file size on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218006/why-does-the-repartition-method-increase-file-size-on-disk)
- [Why cannot reduce the total file size by merging small ORC files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361342/why-cannot-reduce-the-total-file-size-by-merging-small-orc-files)

I have a folder containing 3.3GB of orc files verified by `du -sh`. All files have the same schema and are very small (~128 KB). I believe they have a lot of duplicates, so I'd like to clean them up.

```
$ du -sh /pool/in
3.9G    /pool/in
```

I read this entire folder using this code.

```
# script.py

import pyspark.sql
import pyspark.sql.functions

instance_conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
instance_conf.set('spark.local.dir', '/pool/spark_temp')
instance_conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config(conf=instance_conf).getOrCreate() # create a new sesssion at a host

dirname = "/pool/in"
dirname_out = "/pool/out"
dataframe = spark.read.orc(dirname)
dataframe_out = dataframe.dropDuplicates() # across all columns

dataframe_out.count()
dataframe_out.write.mode("overwrite").orc(dirname_out)
```

I called spark-submit using these settings

```
/usr/local/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 2 script.py
```

And the output folder is now 12GB!

```
$ du -sh /pool/out
12G /pool/out
```

I was not expecting the dropDuplicates() operation to actually triple some large set of data. Are the executor cores reading the data in twice? Why is this happening?

I noticed something was off when even `/pool/out/_temporary` was growing in size.

Just to add more to the confusion...

The amount of files left in each directory differs

```
ls /pool/in | wc -l
10626
ls /pool/out | wc -l
201
```

The deduplication did work since each id is it's own group of data.

```
>>> x = spark.read.orc("/pool/out")
>>> x.count()
401149568
>>> x = spark.read.orc("/pool/in")
>>> x.count()
467271623
>>> x = spark.read.orc("/pool/out")
>>> x.select("id").distinct().count()
21174972
>>> x = spark.read.orc("/pool/in")
>>> x.select("id").distinct().count()
21174972
```

Comment: can you check the size with `ls -la` and look at individual file size and adding it up (ignore the total size displayed)?  ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486529

Comment: @Emma Yes, they produce the same result.

$ ls -lha /pool/in > wtf.txt
$ head -1 wtf.txt
total 3.9G

$ ls -lha /pool/out
total 12G

Comment: do not look at the total size because as link says, total size is same as `du` which shows all blocks size but individual file size shows the "size of file".

Comment: Oh, yes from comparing the du -sh /pool/in/* and ls -lha /pool/in sizes look the same aside from a few kilobyes. Every file in the /pool/out folder is 61 MB though.

Comment: hmm, 61mb * 201 files = >12gb.  hmm so in your env, `du` ~= `ls`.  this is not the issue of `du` vs `ls`.  The other question is in the last code block, you are doing `x.select("id").distinct().count()` but in your actual code you are doing `x.distinct().count()` amongst the all columns.  Have you checked how much reduction you expect to have if you dropDuplicates for all columns?

Comment: Yeah, I verified the reduction in the row count I wanted contextually. It's just strange that combining small orc files takes more disk space.